# Can you create a build using expo without counting for the EAS build count?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, service, build, expo

I am trying to figure out if all the methods to create a build using expo must go through EAS (Expo Application Services) since apparently they limit the free tier to 30 builds per month.

Can I build the web-app locally without an EAS account / 100% for free?

[The documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/) isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/4TjRX90XpEM), using `eas build --local` should do the trick

Comment: Guillem Poy, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough rep to comment so I will ask here and edit/delete later.

Have you tried building your application manually using `android studio` / `xcode`? You should be able to generate a `build` folder for both platforms and open that folder with `android studio` or `xcode`, make, build and run the project to test.

For android:

- Step 1: install OpenJDK
- Step 2: install android studio
- Step 3: `CD` in your application folder and locate `package.json`.
- Step 4: Run `npm android` in the same directory where `package.json` is located

This should open up android studio for you in the same directory and you can start debugging there with the android studio built in emulator. You can also build an APK of your application and install it to your device or connect your mobile device to android studi via `wifi pairing` and install the application on your android.

Comment: Thank you very much for the interest!
Nope, I haven't tried (yet) doing that since this question rose upon considering developing a web-app using expo, so no app exists yet. However, It looks like something like that should work – hopefully even for web (with "npm web"?).
I will try that soon.

Comment: How to generate a build package that opens in android studio?